# Is the order of react-query QueryClientProvider and react-redux Provider important?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-query

Which is recommended?

Is the order irrelevant?

```
<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <Provider store={store}>
        stuff
    </Provider>
</QueryClientProvider>
```

or

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>  
        stuff
    </QueryClientProvider>
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is *not* relevant because neither Provider need to access things from the other Provider (redux doesn't need access to the QueryClient and react-query doesn't need access to the redux store)